# k-bit signed multiplier

Tags: verilog

I am asked to design a 4-bit signed multiplier using only combinational circuits. Verilog code.

I have designed a 4 bit multipler:

The Half adder module

```
module HA(sout,cout,a,b);   //for Half adder mux
 output sout,cout;
 input a,b;
 assign sout=a^b;
 assign cout=(a&b);
endmodule
```

The Full adder module

```
module FA(sout,cout,a,b,cin);   // for full adder mux
 output sout,cout;
 input a,b,cin;
 assign sout=(a^b^cin);
 assign cout=((a&b)|(a&cin)|(b&cin));
endmodule
```

The multiply module

```
module multiply4bits(product,inp1,inp2);
 output [7:0]product;
 input [3:0]inp1;
 input [3:0]inp2;
 assign product[0]=(inp1[0]&inp2[0]);

 wire x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17; //wire range started from [1:17]

 HA HA1(product[1],x1,(inp1[1]&inp2[0]),(inp1[0]&inp2[1]));
 FA FA1(x2,x3,inp1[1]&inp2[1],(inp1[0]&inp2[2]),x1);
 FA FA2(x4,x5,(inp1[1]&inp2[2]),(inp1[0]&inp2[3]),x3);
 HA HA2(x6,x7,(inp1[1]&inp2[3]),x5);
 HA HA3(product[2],x15,x2,(inp1[2]&inp2[0]));
 FA FA5(x14,x16,x4,(inp1[2]&inp2[1]),x15);
 FA FA4(x13,x17,x6,(inp1[2]&inp2[2]),x16);
 FA FA3(x9,x8,x7,(inp1[2]&inp2[3]),x17);
 HA HA4(product[3],x12,x14,(inp1[3]&inp2[0]));
 FA FA8(product[4],x11,x13,(inp1[3]&inp2[1]),x12);
 FA FA7(product[5],x10,x9,(inp1[3]&inp2[2]),x11);
 FA FA6(product[6],product[7],x8,(inp1[3]&inp2[3]),x10);
endmodule
```

I think that is right, but now I need to extend it and add 2's complement at the end?

Comment: Have you tried running simulation?

Comment: I did simulation but it shows me error!

Comment: Look for Pezaris or Baugh-Wooley multipliers, for example http://eee.guc.edu.eg/Courses/Electronics/ELCT706%20Microelectronics%20Lab/winter%202014/Multipliers.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to convert both factors to [sign/magnitude](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation) representation. Be sure to use 1 bit for sign and *4 for magnitude* to avoid overflow for the value -8. XOR the signs and apply that to the result. This can be done in another verilog module, wrapping your `multiply4bits`-module.

This combinatorial function will probably be optimized to something completely different when you look at the synthesis result. There are far better approaches when you want to optimize for resources or delay. Look at [this excellent paper by Ray Andraka](http://www.andraka.com/multipli.php) for an overview.

In your case, [Booth's algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm) would be a good approach.